# sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver not found

Tags: debian, java

I'm configuring a Business Intelligence tool `Yellowfin BI` on my Debian Linux server and I get this error:

```
Error Message:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

I cannot figure out why the `JDBC-ODBC` driver is not found. 
These are the software versions:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Server: Linux biserver 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How do I troubleshoot this problem and where do I need to look for `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`?

Comment: `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is only available on Oracle's JRE, not on OpenJDK. You need to switch to Oracle's JRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was only to be found in the Oracle version but now support is dropped.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html